# Mobile Home Wiring

Tags: lighting

I tried a search for this, but as Its baffling me hardcore and weird variables, I figured I'd post to get my girlfriend happy again.

Her home is a mobile home. A light switch wasn't working, so with a light residential wiring course under my belt, I figured it shouldn't be too hard. Take the switch out, old school style from when it was built in the 80's. 3 different strands coming into 1, which I wasnt a fan of. Other strands go to an outlet and looks to be an overhead light above the stove. Hop to lowes, get size 14 wire, although the wiring is 16 or 18 I'm guessing (Doh!), proceed to pigtail the two strands coming from the outlet and light with a lead off, which then pigtailed to the strand coming in, with a strand going to the switch. I turn it on.. voila. Everything works. A day goes by, nothing works. I'm guessing my pigtails suck, so I tighten down on everything. Now power to a different breaker is off (living room). Hmm. Finagle (is that a word?) a little more, and find the other power to the living room works when the breaker is switched to off, and none of what I waa trying to fix is working. Its either one or the other, or just the living room. I want to go look at the receptacles leading from where I ran strands, as her 5 year old pulls on the plug, but I need an idea of what is going on before I can touch it, so I can surprise her when she comes home one day. Nothing strikes fear like when I try to fix it, after she said leave it alone, and make the living room not work too. I had everything working today, switched a light in a different room, all goes out. At this point I am thinking its not me, but would love to hear some thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: It's you. I'm thinking at this point you pigtailed wires from a three way to a single switch. Do you  have pictures of before you disconnected  the first switch?

Comment: @JACK that will be no for sure... before smartphones that was what the back of the fag packet was for...

Comment: Pictures of the current situation could be helpful as well

Comment: A "cable" is several "wires" wrapped in a sheath.  Please try to use "cable" or "wire", and stop using "strand" as that is something else.

Comment: @JACK That would make sense.  The X-factor would be someone throwing the other switch.

Comment: Sorry after you mention a residential wiring corse you then show you don’t know what a 3 way is or the proper wire gauge used in residential wiring maybe you should take the corse again , this time stay awake as a simple switch with 3 wires is easy to change.